# where is tf.nn.l2_loss defined?

Tags: tensorflow

According to this documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_loss it says

```
Defined in tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py.
```

But when I go to tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py there is no l2_loss defined.

I'm trying to see what would be the difference between using `tf.nn.l2_loss(W)` or just using `tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(W))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/512d3d0868c5131a9a88ad4af0243051bdaff51c/tensorflow/core/kernels/l2loss_op.cc#L36) is the used CPU implementation of it.

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d2d42ee8b3e134de4c11055b695c0e16e6186b73/tensorflow/cc/gradients/nn_grad.cc#L98) is the according gradient implementation.